# Group $G$ isomorphic to direct product $G \times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

I am looking for a group $G$ with $\vert G \vert > 1$ which is isomorphic to the direct product $G \times G$.

I have been looking for such a group among non-finite groups, such as $\mathbb{Z}$ or the group of real-valued sequences. However, for these groups, I could not find an isomorphism to the direct products of themselves. 
Could anyone please give me a hint which particular group might be helpful to consider?

Comment: From the duplicate."It is a fact that $\Bbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^2$ as abelian groups, since they have the same dimension as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$."

Comment: $G=A^{\Bbb N}$ for any $A$ works, with an isomorphism obtained from $\Bbb N=(2\Bbb N)\cup(2\Bbb N+1)$

Comment: @convergence of course that such an example would be an infinite group, because if you have a set $G$ with  $n$ elements, then $G \times G $ will have $n^2$ elements, As a result, no bijection between $G$ and $G\times G$ would exist.